Calling TypeScript function from C# Microservice code
I am trying to call my typescript function in my C# microservice code using below code. But unable to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("./myinternalprojectfolder/filename.min.js");
string script = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();

using (var typescriptEngine = new Jint.Engine()) {
   typescriptEngine.Execute(script);
   var result = typescriptEngine.Invoke("myfunctionname", argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4);
}


Looks like it is loading the script because I am able to see my typescript related details as shown in below screenshot-

But when while executing the Invoke() function, i get below Error.

Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException: 'Can only invoke functions -->
JavaScriptErrorWrapperException: Can only invoke functions

Thanks. I tried the above code.
